# Angular2: Subscribe one Service Method to another Service Method

Tags: angular, ionic2

Let's say I have

**Service_1**

```
setRoot(){ }
```

**Component_1**

```
this.service_1.setRoot();
```

**Service_2**

```
setRoot() { this.nav.setRoot(Component_x) }
```

This is done to avoid circular dependency when using Service_1 in Component_1 until Ionic Team pushes Ionic2 RC1 into Git which has ng2 Routing implemented. But, we need it now.

So I want to listen or subscribe to `service_1.setRoot()` and when it has been called `service_2` should invoke its own method `setRoot()`. At no point `service_1` is allowed to import `service_2`, because `service_2` imports **all Components** itself and this would give circular dependencies all over the place.

Comment: Rc1 would have ng2 routing? You can implement events of ionic and broadcast events to solve your problem

Comment: Yes RC1 will finally be there where it always should have been. We burned serious cash due to missing routing in Ionic-Beta. Can you give an example with above syntax? I give you the answer then.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/

Comment: RC1 is out: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.1